# Compare Lists in datatable

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table(`data`) which looks like the following.

```
  rn    peoplecount 
  1     0,2,0,1
  2     1,1,0,0
  3     0,1,0,5
  4     5,3,0,2
  5     2,2,0,1
  6     1,2,0,3
  7     0,1,0,0
  8     0,2,0,8
  9     8,2,0,0
 10     0,1,0,0
```

My goal is to find out all records which have the 1st element of the present row not matching with 4th element of previous row. In this example, 7th row matches the criteria. How can I get a list of all such records.

My attempt so far.

```
data[,  previous_peoplecount:= c(NA, peoplecount[shift(seq_along(peoplecount), fill = 0)])]
```

This gives a new table as follows:

```
  rn    peoplecount          previous_peoplecount
  1     0,2,0,1                   NA
  2     1,1,0,0              0,2,0,1
  3     0,1,0,5              1,1,0,0
  4     5,3,0,2              0,1,0,5
  5     0,2,0,1              5,3,0,2
  6     1,2,0,3              0,2,0,1
  7     0,1,0,0              1,2,0,3
  8     0,2,0,8              0,1,0,0
  9     8,2,0,0              0,2,0,8
 10     0,1,0,0              8,2,0,0
```

Now I have to fetch all records where 1st element of `people_count` is not equal to 4th element of `previous_peoplecount`. I am stuck at this part. Any suggestions?

Edit: poeplecount is list of numerics.

Comment: You should use `dput(data)` so we don't guess what class `peoplecount` is.

Comment: Agreed. My bad. I have edited the original question to mention the class/type of peoplecount

Comment: does all peoplecount rows contain 4 elements? In my opinion you should avoid list in data.table

Comment: Yes. Exactly 4 elements. I am reading the data(integer []) from a PostresSQL database which gives me returns me a string in the format {1, 2, 3, 4}. And then, i convert it to the numeric list. That's why the peoplecount is as it is. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not satisfied with the answers and came up with my own solution as follows:

```
h<-sapply(data$peoplecount,function(x){x[1]})
t<-sapply(data$peoplecount,function(x){x[4]})
indices<-which(head(t,-1)!=tail(h,-1))
```

Thanks to @Sotos and @minem to push me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something along the lines of removing all but first value and all but last value, and comparing, i.e.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)[, first_pos := sub(',.*', '', peoplecount)][, 
         last_pos_shifted :=  sub('.*,', '', shift(peoplecount))][
                                         first_pos != last_pos_shifted,]
```

which gives,

> ```
>    rn peoplecount first_pos last_pos_shifted
> 1:  7     0,1,0,0         0                3
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I believe the approach could be a better. But this is my mistake for not providing complete information. peoplecount is a list of numerics. In this approach we are making character columns!

Answer (score 1):

I would convert to long format and then select interested elements:

```
dt <- data.table(rn = 1:3, x = lapply(1:3, function(x) x:(x+3)))
dt$x[[2]] <- c(4, 1, 1, 1)
dt
#    rn       x
# 1:  1 1,2,3,4
# 2:  2 4,1,1,1
# 3:  3 3,4,5,6

# convert to long format
dt2 <- dt[, .(rn = rep(rn, each = 4), x = unlist(x))]
dt2[, id:= 1:4]
dtSelected <- dt2[x == shift(x) & id == 4]
dtSelected
#    rn x id
# 1:  2 1  4

dt[dtSelected$rn]
#    rn       x
# 1:  2 4,1,1,1
```